# Do two copies of a case class use twice the memory when only one property is changed, or does Scala reuse immutable values on copy to save memory?

Tags: scala

In the following code I instantiate `Name` once and memory must be allocated to store two strings. I then make a copy of that first object, but only changing one property:

```
case class Name(first: String, last: String)

val original = Name("Freddie", "Mercury")
val copy = original.copy(first = "Robert")
```

My question - since `last` is an immutable `val`, does Scala point `copy.last` to the same string in memory as `original.last` in order to save space?

Comment: Yes it does, this is called structural sharing.

Comment: It's also just easier to do it that way. If you had to implement your own copy method, you wouldn't create a new String or other object every time either

Comment: And short strings are cached in a symbol table anyway on the JVM.

Comment: Technically JVM would allocate memory for Name object twice, and once for each of `String`s. So the memory usage after .copy increases by one `Name` and one `String` (if it needed to allocate memory for this new `String`). It doesn't have to translate to twice the size of memory used before. (answering the question from title).

Answer (score 0):

`Name` would look something like this in Java (output after compiling and decompiling):

```
public Name copy(final String first, final String last) {
    return new Name(first, last);
}

public String copy$default$1() {
    return this.first();
}

public String copy$default$2() {
    return this.last();
}

public String first() {
    return this.first;
}

public String last() {
    return this.last;
}
```

You can see that when you copy a `Name` object, the default second argument is `last()`/`last`, meaning that the `last` field of the newly created `Name` is, as you guessed, pointing to the same object as the original `Name`'s `last` field.

I suppose you could say this is to save the JVM space, but it would also just not make any sense to copy all the fields of a Product instance. `copy` is not `deepCopy`, and if you wanted to copy the original object's fields, where would you stop? Do you also copy the fields of those fields, and so on? And how exactly would you copy a field of type `Foo` without the compiler generating code that does some nasty reflection? It just makes more sense to reuse the fields.